Apex test method code coverage using fflib_ApexMocks is skipping the selector
I am trying to use the fflib_ApexMocks and testing it on my test class but it keeps on skipping the selector in the code coverage.
Please help.
Thank you.
AccountTriggerHandler:
public static void validateOppByAccName(List<Account> newList, Map<Id, Account> oldMap) {
        
        Set<Id> accIdsSet = new Set<Id>();
        List<Account> filteredAccts = new List<Account>();
        
        RecordFinderOpportunity rfOpp = new RecordFinderOpportunity();
            
        for (Account acc : newList) {
            if (acc.Name != oldMap.get(acc.Id).Name) {
                accIdsSet.add(acc.Id);
                filteredAccts.add(acc);
            }
        }
        Map<Id, Id> accIdToOppIdMap = new Map<Id, Id>();
        if(!accIdsSet.isEmpty()) {
            for (Opportunity opp : rfOpp.selectByAccId(accIdsSet)) {
                String oppName = opp.Name;
                if (oppName.contains('a')) {
                    accIdToOppIdMap.put(opp.AccountId, opp.Id);
                }
            }
        }
        
        if (accIdToOppIdMap != null) {
            for (Account acc : filteredAccts) {
                if (accIdToOppIdMap.get(acc.Id) != null) {
                    acc.addError('Do not do that!');
                }
            }
        }
    }

This is the test method: AccountTriggerHandler_Test
@isTest
    private static void testvalidateOppByAccName() {
        fflib_ApexMocks mocks = new fflib_ApexMocks();
        
        Id accId = fflib_IDGenerator.generate(Account.SObjectType);
        Id oppId = fflib_IDGenerator.generate(Opportunity.SObjectType);
        
        List<Account> newAccList = new List<Account>();
        Map<Id, Account> oldAccMap = new Map<Id, Account>();
        
        Account accNew = new Account();
        accNew.Id = accId;
        accNew.Name = 'Acc Name After';
        newAccList.add(accNew);
        
        Account accOld = new Account();
        accOld.Id = accId;
        accOld.Name = 'Acc Name Before';
        oldAccMap.put(accOld.Id, accOld);
        
        Opportunity opp = new Opportunity();
        opp.Id = oppId;
        opp.AccountId = accId;
        
        // create the mock classes
        RecordFinderOpportunity oppSelector = (RecordFinderOpportunity) mocks.mock
            (RecordFinderOpportunity.class);
        
        // stub the mocks
        mocks.startStubbing();
        mocks.when(oppSelector.sObjectType())
            .thenReturn(Opportunity.SObjectType);
        mocks.when(oppSelector.selectByAccId( (Set<Id>)fflib_Match.anyObject() )).
            thenReturn( new List<Opportunity> { opp });
        mocks.stopStubbing();
        
        GenericApplication.Selector.setMock(oppSelector);
        
        test.startTest();
            AccountTriggerHandler.validateOppByAccName(newAccList, oldAccMap);
        test.stopTest();
    }

GenericApplication:
public with sharing class GenericApplication {
    
    public static final fflib_Application.UnitOfWorkFactory unitOfWork = new fflib_Application.UnitOfWorkFactory(new List<SObjectType>{
        Account.SObjectType,
        Contact.SObjectType,
        Opportunity.SObjectType
    });
    
    public static final fflib_Application.ServiceFactory service = new fflib_Application.ServiceFactory(new Map<Type, Type>{
        
    });
    
    public static final fflib_Application.SelectorFactory selector = new fflib_Application.SelectorFactory(new Map<SObjectType, Type>{
        Opportunity.SObjectType => RecordFinderOpportunity.class
    });
    
    public static final fflib_Application.DomainFactory domain = new fflib_Application.DomainFactory(GenericApplication.selector, new Map<SObjectType, Type>{
        
    });
}



The mock for RecordFinderOpportunity is created and stubbed to return a list of opportunities. After the test execution, mocks.verify is used to ensure that the selectByAccId method was called exactly once.
Test Method:
@isTest
private static void testvalidateOppByAccName() {
        fflib_ApexMocks mocks = new fflib_ApexMocks();

        Id accId = fflib_IDGenerator.generate(Account.SObjectType);
        Id oppId = fflib_IDGenerator.generate(Opportunity.SObjectType);

        List<Account> newAccList = new List<Account>();
        Map<Id, Account> oldAccMap = new Map<Id, Account>();

        Account accNew = new Account();
        accNew.Id = accId;
        accNew.Name = 'Acc Name After';
        newAccList.add(accNew);

        Account accOld = new Account();
        accOld.Id = accId;
        accOld.Name = 'Acc Name Before';
        oldAccMap.put(accOld.Id, accOld);

        Opportunity opp = new Opportunity();
        opp.Id = oppId;
        opp.AccountId = accId;

        // Create the mock classes
        RecordFinderOpportunity oppSelector = (RecordFinderOpportunity) mocks.mock(RecordFinderOpportunity.class);

        // Stub the mocks
        mocks.startStubbing();
        mocks.when(oppSelector.sObjectType()).thenReturn(Opportunity.SObjectType);
        mocks.when(oppSelector.selectByAccId((Set<Id>)fflib_Match.anyObject())).thenReturn(new List<Opportunity> { opp });
        mocks.stopStubbing();

        // Set the mock in the GenericApplication
        GenericApplication.Selector.setMock(oppSelector);

        test.startTest();
                AccountTriggerHandler.validateOppByAccName(newAccList, oldAccMap);
        test.stopTest();

        // Verify that the selectByAccId method was called
        ((RecordFinderOpportunity)mocks.verify(oppSelector, mocks.times(1))).selectByAccId((Set<Id>)fflib_Match.anyObject());
}

For more information: https://github.com/apex-enterprise-patterns/fflib-apex-mocks

I got this after adding the mocks.verify: fflib_ApexMocks.ApexMocksException: EXPECTED COUNT: 1
ACTUAL COUNT: 0
METHOD: RecordFinderOpportunity__sfdc_ApexStub.selectByAccId(Set<Id>)
ACTUAL ARGS: ()
EXPECTED ARGS: [any Object]
